# What is the correct interpretation for a number of OCL expressions that use "Shorthand for Collect"?

Tags: ocl

Given the following UML model:

[image]
I am struggling with the correct interpretation of some OCL expressions (all in context of class "City"). The version of OCL I'm working with is OCL 2.3.1 (though if OCL 2.4 is more suited for answering my question, for example because some aspects of OCL are more clear in OCL 2.4, I'm certainly interested).

- If I want to ensure via OCL that each room in the city must have at least one window:

  - Let's forget about making "window" mandatory - the goal of this example is to understand how the OCL expression would need to look like.
  - `inv: self.building.room.window->notEmpty()` - As far as I understand OCL, this does not express the intent, since it means that the collection of all windows in the city must not be empty. The OCL expression uses what OCL 2.3.1 calls "Shorthand for Collect". The expression could also be written as `inv: self.building->collect(room)->collect(window)->notEmpty()`. Is this correct?
  - `inv: self.building.room->forAll(r|r.window->notEmpty())` - This should express the intent - correct?
  - `inv: self.building->forAll(b|b.room->forAll(r|r.window->notEmpty()))` - This should also express the intent - correct?
- Consider that another requirement would be that the area of each room must be greater than 0:

  - `inv: self.building.room.area > 0` - Is this a valid expression? **If** it is:

    - How would this expression be evaluated (if the expression is valid) - with a check that each area value is greater than 0 (forAll), or just that one of the area values is greater than 0 (exists)?
    - In the OCL specification, I could not find anything that tells me if, in this expression, the collection of area values would all need to be greater than 0 (an implicit forAll()), or just one (an implicit exists()). Can you point me to the section(s) of the OCL specification that define the behaviour?
  - `inv: self.building.room->forAll(r|r.area > 0)` - This should express the intent - correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.building.room.window => yes, yes, yes

You have successfully expanded collect in the first example. Do the same in the second, assuming room only has one area.

self->collect(building)->collect(room.area) > 0

which is badly typed: Bag(Integer) > Integer

self->collect(building)->collect(room.area)->size() > 0

is correctly typed but tests whether there is more than one area

self->collect(building)->collect(room.area)->sum() > 0

is correctly typed and detects whether any (assumed non-negative) area is non-zero

self->collect(building)->collect(room)->forAll(area > 0)

tests for non-singleton rooms

(If you use the Eclipse OCL Xtext Console you will see your type errors and intermediate types.)

Comment: So since `inv: self.building.room.area > 0` is badly typed (Bag(Integer) > Integer), it is invalid. And `self->collect(building)->collect(room)->forAll(area > 0)` represents the last expression in my question, and correctly expresses the intent? I just want to make sure that I got this right.

Comment: Yes, so the maximal shorthand could be inv: self.building.room->forAll(area > 0)

Comment: Thank you - also for the tip regarding Eclipse OCL.